# Selenium Desired Capabilites Crashing When Adding Proxy

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, scrapinghub

I have deployed a selenium scraper in scrapinghub cloud using a custom docker container. When running the script I am getting the following error from selenium and I am not sure what is causing this issue when I deploy but not in my local enviorment.

```
File "link_spider.py", line 128, in main
    url_crawler.setUp()
  File "link_spider.py", line 49, in setUp
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities, options=chrome_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

When I run i  virtualenv on my local environment which is ubuntu 18.04 I do not have any issue at all. Below I will paste my setUp method from my class.

```
def setUp(self):
    headless_proxy = "127.0.0.1:3128"
    proxy = Proxy({
        'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
        'httpProxy': headless_proxy,
        'ftpProxy' : headless_proxy,
        'sslProxy' : headless_proxy,
        'noProxy'  : ''
    })
    # path to download files
    path = '/tmp'
    # set the download file to tmp directory
    prefs = {
        "download.default_directory": path,
        "profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2,
    }
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # change the location of the file download
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    # turns off webdriver detection
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
    # disable chrome automation notification
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    capabilities = dict(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
    proxy.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities, options=chrome_options)
    self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(120)
```

Docker file

```
FROM scrapinghub/scrapinghub-stack-scrapy:1.6-py3
RUN apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install zip unzip jq libxml2 libxml2-dev
RUN printf "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main\ndeb-src http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main" > /etc/apt/sources.list


#============================================
# Google Chrome
#============================================
# can specify versions by CHROME_VERSION;
#  e.g. google-chrome-stable=53.0.2785.101-1
#       google-chrome-beta=53.0.2785.92-1
#       google-chrome-unstable=54.0.2840.14-1
#       latest (equivalent to google-chrome-stable)
#       google-chrome-beta  (pull latest beta)
#============================================
ARG CHROME_VERSION="google-chrome-stable"
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
  && apt-get update -qqy \
  && apt-get -qqy install \
    ${CHROME_VERSION:-google-chrome-stable} \
  && rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*

#============================================
# Chrome Webdriver
#============================================
# can specify versions by CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION
# Latest released version will be used by default
#============================================
ARG CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION
RUN CHROME_STRING=$(google-chrome --version) \
  && CHROME_VERSION_STRING=$(echo "${CHROME_STRING}" | grep -oP "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+") \
  && CHROME_MAYOR_VERSION=$(echo "${CHROME_VERSION_STRING%%.*}") \
  && wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/LATEST_RELEASE "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_${CHROME_MAYOR_VERSION}" \
  && CD_VERSION=$(cat "/tmp/LATEST_RELEASE") \
  && rm /tmp/LATEST_RELEASE \
  && if [ -z "$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION" ]; \
     then CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION="${CD_VERSION}"; \
     fi \
  && CD_VERSION=$(echo $CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION) \
  && echo "Using chromedriver version: "$CD_VERSION \
  && wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CD_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
  && rm -rf /opt/selenium/chromedriver \
  && unzip /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /opt/selenium \
  && rm /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
  && mv /opt/selenium/chromedriver /opt/selenium/chromedriver-$CD_VERSION \
  && chmod 755 /opt/selenium/chromedriver-$CD_VERSION \
  && sudo ln -fs /opt/selenium/chromedriver-$CD_VERSION /usr/bin/chromedriver


#============================================
# crawlera-headless-proxy
#============================================

RUN curl -L https://github.com/scrapinghub/crawlera-headless-proxy/releases/download/1.1.1/crawlera-headless-proxy-linux-amd64 -o /usr/local/bin/crawlera-headless-proxy \
 && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/crawlera-headless-proxy

COPY ./start-crawl /usr/local/bin/start-crawl

ENV TERM xterm
ENV SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE cars.settings
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
RUN python setup.py install
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: maybe a silly question as you mentioned that same thing is working in local setup, how you are linking your chromedriver to your script. The error simply states that it is not able to start chrome session with the desired profile settings

Comment: That doesn't seem like the full list of dependencies to me. Also what is that proxy and is it running in the container?

Comment: @Ishan in ubuntu I have the chrome driver installed in usr/bin and when I run selenium it automatically looks for it in that folder hence I dont have to set the executable path. I have done the same in the dockerfile. However, I did observe what you meantioned and have added executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver' but it still failed to launch chrome.

Comment: @pguardiario crawlera proxy and yes it was installed and is running in the container.

Comment: I would ssh to the  container and run chromedriver. It should crash with a helpful message